# Exclude child pages from archive.php

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

I've created a hierarchical custom post type called "Services". Here are the pages I've added within the custom post type:

- Service 1

  - Service Child (Service 1 is Parent)
  - Service Child (Service 1 is Parent)
- Service 2

  - Service Child (Service 2 is Parent)
  - Service Child (Service 2 is Parent)
- Service 3

  - Service Child (Service 3 is Parent)
  - Service Child (Service 3 is Parent)
- Service 4

  - Service Child (Service 4 is Parent)
  - Service Child (Service 4 is Parent)

Is it possible to exclude the child pages from archive-services.php? I was hoping to achieve this using [pre_get_posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts), but it doesn't seem possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it is possible. All you have to do is to set `post_parent` argument to `0`.

```
function remove_children_from_archive( $query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive('my_custom_post_type') ) {
        // of course you'll have to change my_custom_post_type to real slug - probably services
        $query->set( 'post_parent', 0 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'remove_children_from_archive' );
```